# Domain not working using Route 53 pointing to AWS ELB in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have a registered domain **nematix.com**. I created a new A record pointing to my ELB in my Kubernetes cluster with a subdomain **equinox.nematix.com**. I am able to access the ELB using ridiculously long external address. But when I try to access from equinox.nematix.com, I got the output such below, why is this happening?

[can't reach this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oydIh.png)

[Route 53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDPfi.png)

I have tried following numerous guides on Google with no luck, I dont know where I'm doing wrong, I have also make sure to allow all incoming and outbound traffic on the EC2 instances

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have defined a `NS` record for `equinox.nematix.com` where Cloudflare is the target and not AWS.

So the `A` record and all other records in Route53 for this domain are ignored because Cloudflare is now responsible for all settings.

You registered a domain with Route53 correct? In this case, AWS has created a NS record for you. If not, open "Registered domains" in Route53, open "nematix.com" and check "Name server" on the right side. Copy this name servers, create a new `NS` record and use the name servers.

Wait some minutes, open a terminal and execute a `dig nematix.com NS`, now you should see the AWS name servers.

Now your A record should work, execute a `dig equinox.nematix.com A`, you should see the "ridiculously long external address" now, this is the public address of your load balancer.